# Hyperledger Fabric Fabcar error for node enrolladmin.js

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

this is the error that comes out every time i run:node enrollAdmin.js

```
node enrollAdmin.js
module.js:328
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'fabric-client'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/patrick/fabric- 
samples/fabcar/enrollAdmin.js:11:21)
  at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you haven't downloaded the dependencies. Run the command `npm install` in the your `fabric-samples/fabrcar` directory. That will download the node_modules you require.

This article that goes through fabcar might be of assistance: https://medium.com/@grsind19/hyperledger-development-with-in-21-days-day-3-fd24c30f4e54